# Optimizing R code to decrease iteration time

Tags: r, optimization, parallel-processing, query-optimization, compiler-optimization

I have written a code to do a numerical optimization for three parameters. My problem is that the code uses 1h30mins for one iteration, and the optimization do not converge untill 150-200 iterations. I have tried the following to optimize the code:

1. Set parameters on a start value which is "nearby" the optimum.
2. Rewrote all the for loops to sapply
3. Compiled all the functions to increase speed
4. Read up on vectorization, but not sure if its possible to implement in my code.
5. Loaded AWS Viritual Machine. I tried adding GPUs to the viritual machine, but the code is still running on 1h30min.

The code which I am using now:

```
library(stats4)
library(gamlss.dist)
library(lmtest)
library(pbapply)
library(compiler)

bid <- runif(10000, 1.1,1.55)
participants <- round(runif(10000,5,9))
r = 0.5

foo_inner <- function(i, theta1, theta2, lambda){
    function(N){
    density = (
        (N) *
        (N-1) * 
        (pWEI2(bid[i], theta1, theta2))^(N-2) *
        pWEI2(bid[i], theta1, theta2, lower.tail = FALSE) *
        dWEI2(bid[i], theta1, theta2)) /
        (1-(pWEI2(r, theta1, theta2))^N)

    ngittN =
        dbinom(participants[i], size = N, 
               prob = pWEI2(r, theta1, theta2, lower.tail = FALSE))
    sN = 
        dpois(N, lambda)

    return(density * ngittN * sN)
    }}

foo_outer <- function(theta1, theta2, lambda){
            function(i){
            listeObs <- sapply(participants[i]:20000, foo_inner(i, theta1, theta2, lambda))
            return(sum(listeObs))
            }}

eqThree <- function(theta1, theta2, lambda){
    secondPart <- pbsapply(1:length(bid), foo_outer(theta1, theta2, lambda))

    LL <- -sum(log(secondPart))
    return(LL)
}

foo_inner <- cmpfun(foo_inner)
foo_outer <- cmpfun(foo_outer)
eqThree <- cmpfun(eqThree)
mle <- cmpfun(mle)

result_mle <- mle(minuslogl = eqThree, start=list(theta1 = 1,
                                                  theta2 = 2,
                                                  lambda = 7),
                  method="L-BFGS-B", lower=c(0.1,0.1,5),
                  nobs = length(bid))
```

As this is a one-time project (with limited time), I would like to avoid writing the code in a new language (fortran, C++). However, if that is my only solution, then I obviously have no choice.

*I would like to note that I have experience of writing in Python, but based on my initial analysis Python and R have similar problems when it comes to computational power.*

Comment: The code you provided is not directly runnable. For example: where do you get `pWEI2` from? Or `mle`

Comment: Packages added.